# What goes wrong with white?

Tags: online-chess

Can you find the mistake(s) that caused white to lose this game?

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 g6 2. d4 Bg7 3. Nf3 c6 4. Be3 f6 5. Bd3 d5 6. c4 dxe4 7. Bxe4 e5 8. Bc2 Ne7 9. O-O O-O 10. Nc3 exd4 11. Qxd4 Nf5 12. Qxd8 Rxd8 13. Bxf5 Bxf5 14. Rad1 Na6 15. a3 Bd3 16. Rfe1 Bxc4 17. Nd2 Bf7 18. Nde4 Bb3 19. Rxd8+ Rxd8 20. Bxa7 f5 21. Nc5 Nxc5 22. Bxc5 Bf6 23. h3 Kf7 24. g3 Rd2 25. Rb1 Rc2 26. Bb4 Bd4 27. Kh1 Bxf2 28. Nd1 Bxg3 0-1
```

Comment: Link only questions are not acceptable

Comment: You gave your opponent open files and resigned way before you were mated?

Comment: also black rook managed to reach 2nd rank. also black's 2 bishops were active throughout

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a game produced by two beginners, so a oneliner as answer is difficult.

A simple explanation:

> White failed to address the threats posed by black and gave away the initiative without a real reason. Its pieces didn't take part in a game that seemed equal on a material POV.

A more substantial try:

> The game seems equalish (not counting the numerous misplays by both sides) until move 15. `15.a3` is incorrect because it gives away the initiative to black. After the rook and pawn trades (the latter were actually two blunders) Black prepared the decisive 2nd rank infiltration of the rook by preventing Whites rook from entering on e7. White should have prevented `24.-Rd2` at all costs but played unnecessary f and g pawn moves and seems to have counted on the material equality (which is surprising). After the infiltration Black lured the white pieces to the queenside whilest attacking both the K- and Q-side. Without sufficient defense on the K-side, Whites position is lost. `27.Kh1` is the final error since it direcly forfeits the Kings defensive structure. `27.Nd1` could have defended a bit longer, but pushing the b and c pawns and/or playing `Re2` probably seems sufficient to win for Black (and where not far fetched and thus natural moves to play).

Conclusion:

> Black actually played a rather passive and faulty opening (e.g. the `4. f6` move), but White didn't do anything about it. As far as I can conclude from this game, White constantly played his own game without watching the Black threats (or perhaps misjudging/underestimating them). Black on the other hand prevented the (minor) threats of White.

*PS. Probably Stockfish won't like my conclusions, but I did it without computer analysis.*

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer I'll add a specific way to punish your opponent's opening. After 7...e5, White should absolutely take the pawn. After 8.dxe5 fxe5 9.Qxd8+ Kxd8, Black is left with a permanent weakness in the e5 pawn and a horrible bishop on g7

Comment: Black will probably first trade the Q's with check (8.dxe5 Qxd1+ 9.Kxe5 fxe5) and the castling rights for white are gone. In such an open position the loss of tempo is at the least annoying. But I totally agree that the e5 pawn is weak and the g7 bishop is nearly worthless.